# Spring WS - EndpointInterceptor not invoked

Tags: java, interceptor, spring-ws

I'm developing an web service endpoint using spring web services 3.0.1.

I've developed the endpoint and a client. Both works properly.

My problem is that I want to add an interceptor to my endpoint. I'm trying to do it as is explained in the spring documentation.

The code of the interceptor:

```
@Component
public class CustomEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor
{
  private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomEndpointInterceptor.class);

  @Override
  public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception
  {
    LOG.info("Endpoint Request Handling");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception
  {
    LOG.info("Endpoint Response Handling");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception
  {
    LOG.info("Endpoint Exception Handling");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception
  {
    LOG.info("Execute code after completion");
  }
}
```

I've defined a configuration class that extends WsConfigurationSupport. In this class I add my interceptor.

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class Config extends WsConfigurationSupport
{       
  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) 
  {
    interceptors.add(new CustomEndpointInterceptor());   
    super.addInterceptors(interceptors);
         
  }
}
```

My endpoint in really simple:

```
@Endpoint
public class SnsEndpoint
{
  private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "es.message";

  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "testMessage")
  public void testMessage(@RequestPayload TestMessage request)
  {             
    LOGGER.log (Level.INFO, "Noficiacion de alta recibida: " + (mensaje != null));
  }
}
```

And the Spring config file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config />

  <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.server.endpoint,com.server.endpoint.interceptors,com.server.endpoint.config" />

  <sws:annotation-driven />
    
  <sws:static-wsdl id="sns-ws"  location="classpath:/mywsdl.wsdl" />

</beans>
```

I've set a breakpoint in the 'addInterceptors' method, but is not being invoked. So when I do a request, the web service is executed properly, but the endpoint is not being called.

Why 'addInterceptors' method is not being invoked? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It is not necesary the annotation @EnableWs when extending from class "WsConfigurationSupport". Also remove <sws:annotation-driven /> from spring configuration file.